# Is there third party package repository for Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I came from web development/design (still are) and I started to learn Swift 5 for iOS app development. In web development, there's a lot of sites or repo where I can download pre-written codes for the web like packagist.org. My question is, is there a similar site where I can pull pre-written code in Swift so I can extend the functionality of an iOS app? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try dependency managers [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org), [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage), [Swift Package Manager](https://swift.org/package-manager/).

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/), [spm](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/managing-dependencies-using-the-swift-package-manager/)